# Проблема с отсутствием корзины в 1С-Битрикс: 1С:Франчайзи на базе "Стандрт"

Tags: битрикс

Есть *Битрикс Франчайзи* на базе *Стандарта*.
Есть каталог товаров (скорее витрина), но нет корзины покупателя. 
Идеи есть такие:

1. Осуществить возможность добавлять товар из каталога в Заявку.
   Тут я так понимаю нужно как то организовать связь между компонентами *catalog.element* (элемент каталога детально) и *form.result.new* (форма отправки заявки).
   Но тут я слабо представляю как это можно сделать.
2. Создать полноценную корзину покупателя и связать её с каталогом. Для этого,
   я так понимаю, нужно писать модуль. Тут тоже очень все смутно.

Битриксовод я начинающий, поэтому прошу дельного совета.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны такие варианты:

1. Можете перейти на редакцию Франчайзи на базе редакции Бизнес в ней есть корзина.
2. В форму заказа с помощью [API](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/) подтягивать товары для выбора.
3. Использовать решение ["Киоск"](https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ua/solutions/yenisite.market/) из Marketplace 1С-Битрикс. Оно позволяет создать интернет-магазин на редакциях «Старт», «Стандарт», «Эксперт».